# Get last mapped key used in vim

Tags: vim

Is there any way to find the last key used in vim so I could use the same function for multiple things depending on the key pressed.

For instance:

```
nn <F1> :call Fhandler()
nn <F2> :call Fhandler()

fu Fhandler()
  if v:triggerKey == "<F1>"
  elseif v:triggerKey == "<F2>"
  ...
endf
```

For instance, in AutoHotKey I have `A_ThisHotkey` which could be used to setup mentioned proxy function.

Answer (score 2):

Unless we are dealing with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) with your question, why not just do this:

```
nn <F1> :call Fhandler('<F1>')
nn <F2> :call Fhandler('<F2>')

fu Fhandler(key)
  if a:key == "<F1>"
  elseif a:key == "<F2>"
  ...
endf
```

Comment: its not DRY ....

Comment: Isn't the "don't repeat yourself" idea meant for when it's avoidable? In this case you're probably stuck with it.